# Can we plot a feature layer using Well API Number using Arcgis?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have a JSON response which contains well details(well API Number,well name and operator details).I want to know is this json response sufficient to plot a feature layer or do we require the latitude and longitude to plot the features in the feature layer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would help if you added some code to reference.
If you're using ArcGIS Server and the ESRI JavaScript API, and you've done some sort of query operation, then it is possible to request that the geometry be returned along with your well details.

Here's a full sample which describes how to do that: [ESRI JavaScript API QueryTask Example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/query_click.html)

The Key lines of code in there are:

```
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.returnGeometry = true;
```

The .returnGeometry property means that your JSON response will contain the coordinates, which you then display once the QueryTask is complete.

```
   dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function(featureSet) {
      map.graphics.clear();

      var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,255,255,0.35]), 1),new dojo.Color([125,125,125,0.35]));

      //QueryTask returns a featureSet.  Loop through features in the featureSet and add them to the map.
       dojo.forEach(featureSet.features,function(feature){
        var graphic = feature;
        graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
        graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

        map.graphics.add(graphic);

      });

    });
```